# Custom UITableViewCell isn't released or reused after navigation, memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks

I have a class that defines a custom contact cell called ContactItemCell and a xib file that lays out that cell. When I create the table view it opens up and six of these ContactItemCell classes are created. When I navigate back they aren't deallocated, and when I open the tableview again another 6 are created. Here's the tableview code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Contact* contact = [self contactAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *cellID = @"ContactItemWithTagsForBothCell";
    ContactItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactItemWithTagsForBothCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        if (arr.count <= 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"couldnt find cell with ID: %@", cellID);
            return nil;
        }

        cell = [arr firstObject];
    }

    [cell configureCellForContact:contact];

    return cell;
}
```

The fileowner in the xib file is just set to be blank which I'm assuming means NSObject. I've tried looking for a strong reference cycle to see if the class is kept alive by pointers but I haven't seen anything after days of investigation. I'm really at my limit and I'm not sure what else I can do, I've been using instruments too and that's how I've figured out that they're being created 6 at a time but I can't find out what's pointing to them. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong with the table view? If I'm not and you think it's a strong reference cycle then how can I find every object that points to this ContactItemCell? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the memory debugger say? http://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-visual-memory-debugger/

Comment: I'll take a look at that tutorial I've never heard of the memory debugger before, I really appreciate the tip and I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @JoshHomann Dude you saved my life, there's no way I would have found the issue without that tool. Thank you so much. The problem was that the old dev overwrote the base uiviewcontroller and added the tableview to an array, so when the view controller was deallocated the table view wasn't. I wouldn't have found this without the amazing debug memory graph tool. You're awesome bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone was curious I used the memory debugger and found that there was a strong reference cycle with a pod I was using.